# how to receive large number of UDP packets continously in vc++

Tags: sockets, udp

I am writing an GUI application which receives UDP packets from a FPGA board of 4Gb data continuously (application is a data retrieval system).

I created my own class inherited from CAyncSocket and on receive message I am reading packets through ReceiveFrom API and writing data to file.

As packets are sent continuously from FPGA (about 400k packets of 1KB data) my application is missing the packets. I am receiving only 200k packets. but when I am monitoring with Wireshark all packets are received.

Can anyone suggest any technique or algorithm to solve this problem, so that I can receive large number of UDP packets without loss.

Answer (score 5):

The first thing to understand and accept is that you cannot guarantee that no UDP packets will be dropped.  It is part of the nature of the UDP transport layer that any step in the transmission is allowed to drop a UDP packet for any reason, and that this is something that will happen from time to time.  In your case, it sounds like the Windows networking stack is dropping the incoming UDP packets after receiving them from the network card, probably because the incoming-UDP-packets buffer associated with your socket is too full and does not have room to store them.  This could happen for example if your write-to-disk calls occasionally take a number of milliseconds to return, during which time your app is unable to read more data from the UDP socket.

That said, there are a few things you can do to make the dropping of packets somewhat less likely.

The first (and easiest) thing to do is to increase the size of your socket's incoming-packets-buffer, using [setsockopt(SO_RCVBUF)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740476(v=vs.85).aspx).  This helps because the larger the buffer is, the more time your program will have to read packets out of the buffer before the networking stack fills the buffer up entirely and starts dropping packets because it has no place to put them.

If that isn't sufficient for your purposes, the other thing you can do is spawn a separate thread that does nothing but receive incoming UDP packets and add them to a queue (for another thread to process later).  Because this thread does nothing else besides receive UDP packets, it will be able to respond quickly when new packets have arrived, and thus the incoming-sockets-buffer will be less likely to ever fill up and overflow.  You'll probably want to run this thread at a high priority if possible, so that there is less chance of it being held off of the CPU in the case where other threads or programs are competing for CPU time.

If you've implemented both of the above and the rate of packet loss still isn't acceptable, then you may have to step back and re-evaluate your approach.  This might include switching from UDP protocol to TCP, or rewriting your code as an in-kernel driver, or switching to a real-time OS that can make better guarantees about response times.